# How to use the command prompt to disable the guest account

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10

net user or something to disable the guest and/or Administrator account?

Comment: Easy to google: http://www.windows-commandline.com/enable-disable-guest-account/

Comment: @MC10 Easy to google and also, for me, wrong. My experience matches more closely to this google result: http://www.infoworld.com/article/2943718/microsoft-windows/windows-10-build-10159-loses-the-windows-guest-account.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `net user` to modify user accounts.

The following should disable it.

```
net user guest /active:no
```

This must be run as admin.